# SUMIFS where the criteria range is actually the sum of 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

| Item | Day Recieved | Days Kept | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wrench | 3 | 7 | 10.00 |
| Screwdriver | 7 | 19 | 13.00 |
| Hex Key | 14 | 23 | 6.00 |

I want to do a SUMIFS to determine the value of my tools on a certain day.

So, for example, I want to determine, on day 8 what the value of tools I have are. In this case I will have the wrench and the screwdriver, but not the hex key. So I am looking to return the value `23.00`.

Here's what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure it out!

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D4, B2:B4, "<=8", [Day Received + Days Kept], ">8")
```

In the formula above, I'm trying to work out how to add `Day Received (B2:B4)`  to `Days Kept (C2:C4)` and use that as a range for the SUMIFS lookup.

To be clear, for the Wrench, I received it on day 3 and kept it for 7 days, so technically I owned the wrench from day 3 to day 10.

Any ideas? Is this something I can do? Am I thinking about it wrong?

N.B. I don't want to do this by adding a column to the table as this table is actually a pivot table fed from an external datasource and it is used by many people who wouldn't appreciate me adding an extra column each time it's updated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMIFS will not use an array.  Doing the addition creates an array.  Instead switch to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D2:D4, (B2:B4<=8)*(B2:B4+C2:C4>8))
```

SUMPRODUCT works with arrays.  The `(B2:B4<=8)*(B2:B4+C2:C4>8)` will return an array of `1` and `0` which will then be multiplied to the array `D2:D4` and return the correct sum.

[image]

If you really want SUMIFS, it will require a helper column that does the addition so you can refer to a range and not an array:

So in E2:E4, I added B2:B4 to C2:C4.  I used:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D4, B2:B4, "<=8",E2:E4,">8")
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks Scott! I didn't know about SUMPRODUCT!